# Finding a closed formula for the nth Lucas Number

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, closed-form, lucas-numbers

The Lucas numbers are defined by 
$$L_0 = 1, L_1=3$$   $$L_n = L_{n-2} + L_{n-1}$$

I used this knowledge to get an equation for the nth Lucas number as follows:
$$L(x) = \frac{1+2x}{1-x-x^2}$$

Now I am asked to find a closed formula for this equation and was wondering how I would make this equation be in closed form.

Comment: That "equation" you have is no equation.... it's a Generating Function

Comment: @Brevan: It’s also an equation, namely $$\sum_{n\ge 0}L_nx^n=\frac{1+2x}{1-x-x^2}\;.$$

Comment: If the generating function $L(x)$ is the starting point for obtaining your closed form for the members of the sequence $L_n$, you should explain how you derived it from the recurrence and $L_0$, $L_1$, as this may prove helpful.

Comment: Decompose $L(x)$ into partial fractions. Then express each of the partial fractions as a power series; you don’t need to know any power series fancier than geometric series for this. Finally, add the two power series to get a single power series: the coefficient of $x^n$ will be $L_n$, but you’ll have it in an explicit form.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott true, however the OP said it was an equation for the "nth Lucas number". I would say that is not true because the LHS is not the nth Lucas number but instead a sum *including* the nth Lucas number (and all others for the record). Nevertheless, I see your point

Comment: @Brevan I guess the answer was staring me right in the face